# Postgres: Map varchar primary key to int ids for better performance

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a very modest server to work with, but quite a lot of data (+50GB).

I gather daily prices from products and store them. Since I work with external systems, the ids of the products and shops are varchars.

The tables nowadays look like this:

```
products (about 10k rows)
------------
id varchar
other data..

shops (about 3k rows)
------------
id varchar
other data..

prices (more than 100 million rows!!)
-------------------------------
id_price serial (autoincrement)
id_product varchar
id_shop varchar
date
```

The hard table to deal with is `prices`, which consumes about 50% of the database, plus other 40% for indexes (almost 90% of the entire database!)

The varchar ids are generally around 10 characters each, encoded in utf8, although they are all ascii characters.

**My question is** whether it's worth to change the varchar ids to numerical ids to allow **1)** reduction in the size of the table and **2)** speedup of queries (particularly scans and joins, perhaps thanks to less pages to read from disk?)

I was thinking about adding autoincrement keys to both `products` and `shops` tables and then altering the `prices` table to point to the new values. Notice that this process will be pretty hefty with my modest server, and that's why I haven't been able to test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

A 10 digits number needs to be stored as `big integer`. Depending on what is the maximum and medium `varchar` sizes the storage reduction can be big:

```
select
    pg_column_size('9223372036854775807'::varchar(18)) as varchar18,
    pg_column_size(''::varchar(18)) as empty_varchar18,
    pg_column_size('9223372036'::varchar(12)) as varchar12,
    pg_column_size(9223372036854775807) as bigint
;
 varchar18 | empty_varchar18 | varchar12 | bigint 
-----------+-----------------+-----------+--------
        22 |               4 |        14 |      8
```

Smaller tables and indexes will have a positive impact on performance.